# How to switch Wired connections in Elementary OS?

Tags: release-loki, ethernet

I've created two wired connections
* Wired Connection1
* Wired Connection2

Wired connection 1 is assigned a `static IP` address.
Wired connection 2 is set to get `Dynamic IP` automatically.

When I connected my system to LAN network through an ethernet cable, `Wired` is enabled (It displays connection in blue color). It has connected to Wired connection 1. But I want to switch to Wired connection 2. I don't see a way to switch these networks in Elementary OS.
Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is to run the command

```
$ nmcli connection show
NAME      UUID                                  TYPE          DEVICE  

Wired1    49b2a5bb-3104-4d4d-a2d6-ec39d3d7c75c  802-3-ethernet  enp0s25 
Wireless1 420a1462-c582-430c-9acc-a326b900f8e5  802-11-wireless wlp3s0
```

It will show which connections are active. Then, if I want to switch my wired connection I run

```
$ nmcli device disconnect enp0s25
Device 'enp0s25' successfully disconnected.
```

Finally, I active another connection running

```
$ nmcli connection up Wired2
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: 
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12)
```

Comment: Though I can't control connections through GUI, CLI alternately is very easy to use. Exactly what I needed. I created aliases for switching wired connections. Thanks.